# instantaneous volume growth rate of cylinder

Tags: derivatives

Radius of a cylinder grows with speed = $2\ \mathrm{cm/s}$ and its height grows with speed = $3\ \mathrm{cm/s}$.

What is the instantaneous volume growth rate of the cylinder when radius = $5\ \mathrm{cm}$ and height = $15\ \mathrm{cm}$?

With only one variable changing , I can take the volume derivate to respect to it and then substitute it, but I can not figure out how to do it with radius and height increasing at the same time with different rates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try to write the volume increase:
$$V=\pi R^2h\\V+dV=\pi (R+dR)^2(h+dh)$$
Then, keeping only first order terms $$dV=\pi(R+dR)^2(h+dh)-\pi R^2 h\\\approx\pi R(2dR)h+\pi R^2dh$$
Then $$\frac{dV}{dt}=2\pi Rh\frac{dR}{dt}+\pi R^2\frac{dh}{dt}$$

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, the volume growth rate will be 375pi?

Comment: That seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the other answer but emphasises the use of product and chain rules.

$V = \pi r^2 h$

$$\frac {dV} {dt} = \pi \left(\frac{d r^2} {dt } h + r^2\frac {dh} {dt}\right ) $$

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =   \pi \left(\frac{d r^2} {dr } \frac {dr} {dt} h + r^2\frac {dh} {dt} \right)$$

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =  \pi \left(2r h \frac {dr} {dt} + r^2\frac {dh} {dt}\right)$$

And now you can substitute the relevant parameters.